# how to set header method POST via postman when csrf token invalid

Tags: node.js, express, token, csrf, postman

How can I set header method POST via postman for a csrf token?  I am using postman Version 4.10.7.  I am getting the error

> ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token

on postman but in the normal test via view on browser it is working.

Comment: Your server is checking for a CSRF token. When you use the form in a browser it is probably a hidden field in the form. Postman doesn't have this. Your server seems to be configured to explicitly prevent people from doing what you are doing.

Comment: ok thank, any example for this dude?

Comment: What is the ultimate goal?  If you are doing something on the page (async form submission) you can use a jQuery plugin to handle it.  If you are building a one page JS app, you probably need to change the server.